# UIView transform.scaleBy animation not working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I was doing some hobbyist programming for iOS in Objective C, but dropped out around the time Apple transitioned to Swift. Very recently started trying to learn Swift, and cobbled together a very simple app just to start understanding it.

I have a screen that starts with a UIView, and three buttons, as shown. The "Grow it" button is intended to make the view (`redBox`) scale up, and the "Shrink it" button should do the opposite. The "Change color" button changes `redBox`'s background color to a random color. All of the changes are intended to be animated using `UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations:`

The color change works, but the scaling doesn't. Hoping someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.

Here's the code, and all help appreciated:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

public extension UIColor {
    public static var random: UIColor {
        let max = CGFloat(UInt32.max)
        let red = CGFloat(arc4random()) / max
        let green = CGFloat(arc4random()) / max
        let blue = CGFloat(arc4random()) / max

        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var redBox: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func growBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.redBox.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    },completion: nil)
    }



    @IBAction func shrinkIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.redBox.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        },completion: nil)

    }



    @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.redBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
    }, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Edit 1:

Per answer below, I changed the transformation code to:

```
@IBAction func growBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    self.redBox.transform = self.redBox.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.05, y: 1.05)
},completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func shrinkIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.redBox.transform = self.redBox.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.95238, y: 0.95238)
    },completion: nil)

}
```

While this seems to work, the "shrink" transform leaves some vestiges, like so:

[image]

Anybody know what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you made here is that you thought `scaledBy` will change the `transform` property.

It doesn't. The method names in Swift can actually tell you whether they will mutate the object on which they are called or not! See how it's named `scaledBy` (with a `d`) instead of `scaleBy`. This suggests that this method will return a new transformation that is scaled. Because in English, you would say something like this:

> I would like this view's transformation to be this particular transformation, but scale***d*** by a factor of 2

In code you can write it like this:

```
thisView.transform = thisParticularTransformation.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
```

This is how `scaledBy` is supposed to be used.

If you want to change the view's transformation to an absolute one (as in not relative to another transformation), you need to create a new `CGAffineTransform`:

```
self.redBox.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see edit above, in which I used a slightly modified version of your suggested code.

Comment: @rattletrap99 So you want the transformation to be relative to the transformation already performed?

Comment: Exactly correct! To grow with each successive tap on the grow button, and vice versa on the shrink button...

Comment: @rattletrap99 I don't see what you are seeing though. Can you try running it on another simulator or on a real device?

Comment: I was guessing it might be a simulator issue. I will experiment with some different one in the morning. Many thanks for your help, but it’s 2:18 AM here, and the lights are going out. I’ll get back to you tomorrow with some results. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sweeper--I accepted and up voted your answer. Many thanks for showing me the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@IBAction func growBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.redBox.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just did't change the transform, that's why it not working

You should create new AffineTransform object and assign into it.

Replace

```
self.redBox.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
```

with

```
self.redBox.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@IBAction func growBox(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.redView.transform = self.redView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    },completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.